# How to add 'data-value' to the title of the page in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, tags, wordpress-shortcode

I want to add some custom JS functionality to my page. For this I want to add a value into the 'data-value' tag of the title.

What I want in HTML code is this:
`<h1  id="h" data-value="HYPERPLEXED">HYPERPLEXED</h1>`

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the custom HTML widget and write your HTML in there.

You can find the custom HTML widget by pressing the add widget (plus sign with blue background) button on the top left of the toolbar.

[image: Custom HTML widget]

[image: Custom HTML widget with content]